# I am trying to join two tables in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, join

I want to join two tables in ASP.NET

this is my repository

```
   public IEnumerable<NightsAndVisitors> GetJoinedData()
        {
            var dataList = (from p in portalContext.visitors
                            join pm in portalContext.Night on p.CountryId equals pm.CountryId
                            select new NightsAndVisitors()
                           {
                              YearNo=p.YearNo,
                              MonthNo=p.MonthNo,
                              CountryId=p.CountryId,
                              CountryNameGe=p.CountryNameGe,
                              tourType=p.tourType,
                              gender=p.gender,
                              ageGroup=p.ageGroup,
                              Value=p.Value,
                              Nights=pm.Value
                          }).ToList();

            return dataList;
        }
```

this is my context

```
  public class TourismPortalContext : DbContext
    {
        public TourismPortalContext(DbContextOptions<TourismPortalContext> options):
            base(options)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<VisitorDto>()
                .HasNoKey();
            modelBuilder.Entity<NightsDto>()
                .HasNoKey();
        }
        public DbSet<VisitorDto> visitors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<NightsDto> Night { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this is my controller

```
[HttpGet("Joined")]
        public List<NightsAndVisitors> GetJoinedData()
        {
            return NightRepository.GetJoinedData().ToList();


        }
```

I dont have any typeerror or somethin like that. I added migration. In models everythiing is OK. when I run localhost/project/Joined it just loading. I want to return json. can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you provide the DbContext options configuration parameter you are using?

Comment: How do you fetch the data on your view? Normally you would have f.i. an  `Index.cshtml` and an `Index()` method on your controller. You return the list using `return View(list);` But that does not seem to be the case here. We would need more details of your project.

Comment: @PaulSinnema I want to return json, which i will use in Angular

Comment: Show it to us, please.

Comment: @PaulSinnema what DbContext options?

Comment: You want to get JSON from the DbContext. That's not possible for as far as I know. You will need to serialize the the list using f.i. NewtonSoft.Json.

Comment: @Irakli ASP.NET is a web app framework, it doesn't talk to databases, much less perform joins. You're actually asking about an ORM, Entity Framework, which *shouldn't* need JOINs in the first place. ORMs deal with entities, not tables. It's the ORM's job to generate JOINs from the relations between entities. If you ask for `Blog.Where(b=>b.ID=123).Select(b=>b.Posts)` the ORM will generate `blobs inner join posts on blobs.ID=posts.BlobId where blobs.ID=123`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, I am new in .NET. is ORM only way to join entities (tables) in ASP.NET?

Comment: You DON'T need JOINs when you have an ORM. That's why they exist in the first place - to remove raw SQL from application code. What you try to do though is generate a report. That should be done with SQL, perhaps using a view. You can map that view to DTOs if you want. It's a lot easier to write a reporting query or view directly than try to do so indirectly through LINQ

Comment: B.t.w. I would not name the entities .....Dto. They are entities and they are tracked by the Entity Framework for changes. A DTO is just that, an object to transfer data.

Comment: Store the results in a variable, debug your application and inspect the results. You can also [*log* the query generated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/) by Entity Framework and execute it yourself. Is it what you expected? Does it join the wrong fields or even tables? You can use the database's tools to inspect the actual queries. In SQL Server you can do that using Extended Events. I suspect the query returns no results. You'll have to check why that happens - we don't know what the actual data are. Perhaps there are really no results to return?

Comment: Can you even make a joined table on keyless tables using a key that you haven't defined in the code you've shared with us? And why make tables of Dto-types? that's not the purpose of dto's. You're messing a lot things up. Maybe start with a detailed configuration that makes sense and clearly defining, porperties, keys and fk's. And than the thing you want to do can be easily achieved by using linq on those tables. Let us know if you have redefined your DbContext (configuration and tables) and please share the entity-types you use. Make your dbset's on your entities not on Dto's.

Comment: Or rename your entities in a correct manner (without the dto-suffix). Take care and good luck.

Comment: @qqtf Thanks, I just joined tables in database. it was best solution for me now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are communicating with an Angular front-end, utilize ASP.NETs API response. To get JSON, you may use:

```
   [HttpGet("Joined")]
    public ActionResult GetJoinedData()
    {
        return Ok(NightRepository.GetJoinedData().ToList());


    }
```

Comment: Why? Simply returning the data has the same effect. If the response is empty, it's because there are no data